# MYSQL Select ID in modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-modal

Please help me! I do not have enough experience in jquery to find this solution by myself.

I display a table from a database. I have 2 rows with an image (logo) that is displayed correctly. When I want to change the logo, I open the modal window.

My question is: In the modal window, how to display the image of the current Logo that i'm trying to modify?

I thought that I simply need to use the ID of the rows to make a "sql select" but after a lot of research I capitulate.

The ID of the row is well displayed in modal windows but impossible to use this in a variable to make a sql requete.

**An exemple**
[image: An exemple]

Below my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      <?php  
         // Create connection
         include('../connection.php');

         // Request
         $requete = $pdo->prepare( '
         SELECT *
         FROM setting S;'
         );
         $requete->execute();
         $datas = $requete->fetchAll();
       ?>   

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- FooTable Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/compiled/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles -->
  <link href="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/js/demo-rows.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="docs">

  <!-- Header -->
  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="docs-section">

      <div class="example">
        <table id="editing-example" class="table" data-paging="true" data-filtering="false" data-sorting="false">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-name="id" data-breakpoints="xs" data-type="number">ID</th>
              <th data-name="nom_config">Name</th>
              <th data-name="img_logo_content">Logo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php foreach( $datas as $data ) { ?>
            <tr data-expanded="true">
              <td>
                <?php echo $data->id; ?></td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $data->nom_config; ?></td>
              <td>
                <?php echo '<img height="20" src="data:image;base64,' . $data->img_logo_content . '">' ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="editor-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editor-title">
          <style scoped>

            .form-group.required .control-label:after {
              content: "*";
              color: red;
              margin-left: 4px;
            }
          </style>
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <form class="modal-content form-horizontal" id="editor">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="editor-title">Add Row</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                <input type="number" id="id" name="id" class="hidden" />

                <div class="form-group required">
                  <label for="nom_config" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom_config" name="nom_config" required>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <?php
                //*************************************************************
                // PROBLEME HERE !!! Find the logo picture from sql database
                $sql = "select * from setting WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $img_logo=  '<img height="50" src="data:image;base64,' . $row[22] . '">';
                }
                //*************************************************************
                ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="img_logo_content" class="col-sm-4 control-label">logo</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">

                    <?php // Display Logo
                    echo $img_logo;
                    ?>

                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img_logo_content" name="img_logo_content" placeholder="Votre Logo">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/js/prism.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/compiled/footable.js"></script>
        <!-- Initialize FooTable -->
        <script>
          jQuery(function($) {
            var $modal = $('#editor-modal'),
              $editor = $('#editor'),
              $editorTitle = $('#editor-title'),
              ft = FooTable.init('#editing-example', {
                editing: {
                  enabled: true,
                  addRow: function() {
                    $modal.removeData('row');
                    $editor[0].reset();
                    $editorTitle.text('Add a new row');
                    $modal.modal('show');
                  },
                  editRow: function(row) {
                    var values = row.val();
                    $editor.find('#id').val(values.id);
                    $editor.find('#nom_config').val(values.nom_config);
                    $editor.find('#img_logo_name').val(values.img_logo_name);

                    $modal.data('row', row);
                    $editorTitle.text('Edit row #' + values.id);
                    $modal.modal('show');
                  },
                  deleteRow: function(row) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the row?')) {
                      row.delete();
                    }
                  }
                }
              }),
              uid = 10;

            $editor.on('submit', function(e) {
              if (this.checkValidity && !this.checkValidity()) return;
              e.preventDefault();
              var row = $modal.data('row'),
                values = {
                  id: $editor.find('#id').val(),
                  nom_config: $editor.find('#nom_config').val(),
                  img_logo_name: $editor.find('#img_logo_name').val()
                };

              if (row instanceof FooTable.Row) {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'update.php',
                  dataType: "json",
                  cache: false,
                  data: {
                    id: values['id'],
                    nom_config: values['nom_config'],
                    img_logo_content: values['img_logo_content']
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data.return) {
                      alert("Success");
                      row.val(values);
                    } else {
                      alert("No modifications!");
                    }
                  },
                });


              } else {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'insert.php',
                  data: {
                    id: values['id'],
                    nom_config: values['nom_config'],
                    img_logo_content: values['img_logo_content']
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data.return) {
                      alert("Success");
                      ft.rows.add(values);
                      location.reload();
                    } else {
                      alert("Already used!");
                    }
                  },

                });
              }
              $modal.modal('hide');
            });
          });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you ! But there is display always the same image???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally got the solution for the second option (API).

Add below code

```
 $('#editor-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var productID= $( "#id" ).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"test_api.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{productID:productID},
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data)
            {   
                $('#logo-preview').html(data); 
            }
        })
     });
```

Create the below file : test_api.php

```
<?php
include('../connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['productID'])) {
$productID = $_POST['productID'];

$sql = "select * from setting WHERE id='" . $productID . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(isset($result)){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (count($row) > 0) {
        $data = '<img height="50" src="data:image;base64,' . $row['img_logo_content'] . '">';
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Thank thaihoc06 !

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$row[22]` contain the exact value you are expecting.

Try the following code:

```
$sql = "select * from setting WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(isset($result)){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (count($row) > 0) {
        //use proper array key name
        //if db column name name is logo then you can access it like $row['logo']
        $img_logo = '<img height="50" src="data:image;base64,' . $row['logo'] . '">';
    } else {
        //count is zero
        echo 'count is zero';
    }
} else {
    //result is empty
    echo 'result is empty';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes , there is exact value in $row[22]

Comment: Compare values in $data->img_logo_content and $row[22]. I think that is your problem.

Comment: The mistake is not between $data>img_logo_content and $row[22] but because the $id value do not exist. How to declare this value ?

Comment: I forgot to say that with this code, I always have the last ID of my array. (When I click the row  1, it's $id of row 2)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to do this:

- Call an API to get row detail when open the modal, then use
  img_logo_content from API response to display. This option will be
  useful if you try to display a value which not displayed in the table.
- Get img_logo_content from the table and display to the modal (see example below)

If you choose second option, you can do as below:

1. Remove below code:

```
                <?php
                //*************************************************************
                // PROBLEME HERE !!! Find the logo picture from sql database
                $sql = "select * from setting WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $img_logo=  '<img height="50" src="data:image;base64,' . $row[22] . '">';
                }
                //*************************************************************
                ?>
```

2. Change below code:

```
                   <?php // Display Logo
                    echo $img_logo;
                    ?>
```

To below:

```
                    <!-- Display logo -->
                    <div id="logo-preview"></div>
```

And please also change below code:

```
$editor.find('#img_logo_name').val(values.img_logo_name);
```

to below:

```
$editor.find('#logo-preview').html(values.img_logo_content);
```

Here is the full code of your **body**:

```
<body class="docs">

  <!-- Header -->
  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="docs-section">

      <div class="example">
        <table id="editing-example" class="table" data-paging="true" data-filtering="false" data-sorting="false">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-name="id" data-breakpoints="xs" data-type="number">ID</th>
              <th data-name="nom_config">Name</th>
              <th data-name="img_logo_content">Logo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php foreach( $datas as $data ) { ?>
            <tr data-expanded="true">
              <td>
                <?php echo $data->id; ?></td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $data->nom_config; ?></td>
              <td>
                <?php echo '<img height="20" src="data:image;base64,' . $data->img_logo_content . '">' ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="editor-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editor-title">
          <style scoped>

            .form-group.required .control-label:after {
              content: "*";
              color: red;
              margin-left: 4px;
            }
          </style>
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <form class="modal-content form-horizontal" id="editor">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="editor-title">Add Row</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                <input type="number" id="id" name="id" class="hidden" />

                <div class="form-group required">
                  <label for="nom_config" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom_config" name="nom_config" required>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="img_logo_content" class="col-sm-4 control-label">logo</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">

                    <!-- Display logo -->
                    <div id="logo-preview"></div>

                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img_logo_content" name="img_logo_content" placeholder="Votre Logo">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/js/prism.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/compiled/footable.js"></script>
        <!-- Initialize FooTable -->
        <script>
          jQuery(function($) {
            var $modal = $('#editor-modal'),
              $editor = $('#editor'),
              $editorTitle = $('#editor-title'),
              ft = FooTable.init('#editing-example', {
                editing: {
                  enabled: true,
                  addRow: function() {
                    $modal.removeData('row');
                    $editor[0].reset();
                    $editorTitle.text('Add a new row');
                    $modal.modal('show');
                  },
                  editRow: function(row) {
                    var values = row.val();
                    $editor.find('#id').val(values.id);
                    $editor.find('#nom_config').val(values.nom_config);
                    $editor.find('#logo-preview').html(values.img_logo_content);

                    $modal.data('row', row);
                    $editorTitle.text('Edit row #' + values.id);
                    $modal.modal('show');
                  },
                  deleteRow: function(row) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the row?')) {
                      row.delete();
                    }
                  }
                }
              }),
              uid = 10;

            $editor.on('submit', function(e) {
              if (this.checkValidity && !this.checkValidity()) return;
              e.preventDefault();
              var row = $modal.data('row'),
                values = {
                  id: $editor.find('#id').val(),
                  nom_config: $editor.find('#nom_config').val(),
                  img_logo_name: $editor.find('#img_logo_name').val()
                };

              if (row instanceof FooTable.Row) {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'update.php',
                  dataType: "json",
                  cache: false,
                  data: {
                    id: values['id'],
                    nom_config: values['nom_config'],
                    img_logo_content: values['img_logo_content']
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data.return) {
                      alert("Success");
                      row.val(values);
                    } else {
                      alert("No modifications!");
                    }
                  },
                });


              } else {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'insert.php',
                  data: {
                    id: values['id'],
                    nom_config: values['nom_config'],
                    img_logo_content: values['img_logo_content']
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    if (data.return) {
                      alert("Success");
                      ft.rows.add(values);
                      location.reload();
                    } else {
                      alert("Already used!");
                    }
                  },

                });
              }
              $modal.modal('hide');
            });
          });
        </script>
</body>
```

Sorry for my bad English :) Hope this help!

Comment: Thank a lot for your help, it works fine right now ! i will try to understand my mistake later.. not enought time right now

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to accept my answer :D

Comment: A last question. If I want to use a request sql in my modal window like the code that you ask me to remove,  is it possible and how to prepare the jquery code ? I'm looking for this since a long time.

Comment: You can't. All PHP code will be executed before send the output (HTML) to the browser, so when you click open the modal, you can't execute PHP code again. The solution is create an API that run SQL query then return row detail, then use these information to display into the modal.

Comment: I think I've finally got the solution for the second option (API).
What do you think?

Comment: @Canta I have some improve for your code, you can check it here: https://pastebin.com/LePCieTR